# Combining yard docs for multiple gems

Tags: ruby, yard

I'm using [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) to generate docs for a couple projects that I'm working on. In one, I'm co-developing a gem that hosts a lot of redundant and shared resources that will be used by other projects.

What'd I'd like is for references from the first project to classes or methods in the gem to show up in the docs for the main project. For example

Gem

```
class Widget
  # Spins the widget of course.
  def spin
  end
end
```

Project

```
class SpecialWidget
  # Jump and {#spin}.
  def dance
  end
end
```

I'd like the docs for SpecialWidget to generate an actual link to the Widget#spin method.

Can this be done?